# ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.recycleview:recyclerview:1.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview, build

I have Error comment

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.recycleview:recyclerview:1.1.0" and
>   "ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.3.0"
>   as below;
>
> ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.recycleview:recyclerview:1.0.0
>
> Add Google Maven repository and sync project
>
> Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.3.0
>
> Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Affected Modules: app

How can I solve these errors? Please advise.

`build.gradle` code is as below;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.github.stack07142.firebase_photos"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {

        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.42.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recycleview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven{
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
        maven{url'http://maven.fabric.io/public'}
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please post your top level `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

```
   implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
   implementation 'androidx.recycleview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Thank you quick answer. I changed to (implementation 'androidx.recycleview:recyclerview:1.1.0' ) however, still have same error.

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.recycleview:recycleview:1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to add google() in your project Top-level build file like that

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        google()
    }
...
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        google()
}
```